# Change operator in pipe based on data

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I want to achieve the following behaviour:

```js
source$.pipe(
  filter(...),
  map(...),
  /* and then switchMap or concatMap based on provided value */
);
```

Is there any if...else or switch...case rxjs function which will return operator based on data from the pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use merge operator with conditional filtering,then only one condition will be fullfilled from a single source$.

```
concatStream=source=>source
.pipe(.filter(..your condition)
switchMap(...))

switchStream=source=>source
.pipe(
.filter(..your condition)
switchMap(...))

merge(concat(source$),switch(source$)).subscribe()
```